# Laptop power supply from 12V source?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm looking for a way to supply 19V at 6.32A, with an input voltage of 11.5-15V.

I'm currently using a pure-sine 1000w inverter + OEM 120w power supply. It draws about 3.33 A at 11.96V (40w). The laptop self-reports to using approx 25w, giving an efficiency of ~60-70%.

I've looked at a previous [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10107/powering-laptop-from-12v-sources-without-inverter), which suggested:

- building one from scratch (I don't know how to do it)
- buying an OEM "car" power supply (I haven't found any that support 120w, only 90w)
- using a boost converter from eBay/Aliexpress

Non-OEM "car" power supplies exist which support 120w. Most seem to be cheap crap. I bought a branded one ("Lavolta") which had good reviews on Amazon, but first it refused to charge the battery until I turned off/on the computer. Then it fried my battery. Maybe it produced voltage spikes higher than 19V.

I already have a [6A DC-DC boost converter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/FREE-SHIPPING-5PCS-LOT-150W-Boost-Converter-DC-to-DC-10-32V-to-12-35V-Step/1886880830.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_6_10065_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10054_10059_10099_10078_10079_426_10073_10103_10102_10096_10052_10050_10051,searchweb201603_9&btsid=e49cc419-0c60-4bab-8b3d-4ad56d60e17a) that I bought from AliExpress. But when adjusting the potentiometer, the voltage can jump quite a bit +/- 1v.

My conclusion is that the cheapest and simplest solution is to use the DC-DC boost converter, but add some over-voltage protection, perhaps with a crowbar circuit.

Is there a better way? Any suggestions for the components I should use in the crowbar circuit?

Comment: Crowbar circuit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_%28circuit%29

Comment: Why not use a car charger? I'm not too familiar with them, but cars fundamentally use 12V so it should be good. Probably you could even find and OEM car charger. Although 15V seems a little high for this kind of things.

Comment: As I mentioned, the OEM chargers are typically only available at 90w, which is meant for use with smaller laptops. The non-OEM chargers are also mostly 90w, although a few exist at 120w. Unfortunately, they all seem to be of horrific quality, as is evidenced by mostly bad reviews on almost all such chargers found on Amazon. As I mentioned, I even tried to buy one such charger, and it fried my battery. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in what I wrote?

Comment: Replace the pot on your DC to DC converter with fixed resistor values. You shouldn't need a crowbar either.

Comment: Why do you need more than 90W?  You said yourself the laptop reports using 25W.

Comment: As far as I know, the computer will typically be able to detect if an underpowered power supply is connected, and will refuse to charge the batteries. Example http://media.askvg.com/articles/images5/AC_Adapter_Warning_Message_Laptop_Startup.png

Answer (score 1):

The DC-DC converter route is, by far, the simplest and most efficient solution.

That being said, with DC-DC's you do tend to get what you pay for. A nice CUI or MuRata (name brand) DC-DC likely will keep your laptop safe. As you noted, off-brand products, may need some sort of filter on their output to avoid voltage spikes.

The issue you are seeing with the potentiometer is likely because they used a dirt-cheap and low-grade pot, with poor linearity or a dirty wiper. Once you adjust it to the right voltage, you can use some stiff epoxy/glue to lock it into place, and it should be fine.

For the crowbar circuit, a 20V Zener diode and 6A fuse are what you'd want. That's the simplest, albeit not *great*; it'll still allow voltage spikes, but at least keep them contained to about 24V. A large capacitor (the DC-DC converter should list the maximum capacitance it can tolerate in its datasheet) would help, too.

One final consideration: the high-power laptop chargers often have some level of intelligence to them. My HP laptop, for example, *knows* when I plug in a non-OEM charger, and complains about that; it will still charge, but at a reduced rate.